# What's the correct way to get another Model's info in Django serializer?

Tags: django, django-serializer

Say I have a serializer A

```
class SerializerA(ModelSerializer):
    some_field = CharField()
    some_other_field = CharField()
    field_require_other_model = SerializerMethodField()
    class Meta:
        model = ModelA
        fields = ('some_field', 'some_other_field', 'field_require_other_model')

    def get_field_require_other_model(self, instance):
        other_model_qs = ModelB.objects.filter(email=instance.email)
        # say I want to get whatever that comes first
        return other_model_qs.first().useful_info
```

As seen above, `SerializerA` uses `ModelA` for getting all the fields except that one in `ModelB`. I can get the info from `ModelB` doing what I did, but I don't know if this is the best way getting the data. I'm not sure if I need to hit database so many times or if there's a way to lazily evaluate it.

Also, what if I have another `SerializerMethodField()` that utilizes `ModelB` but for different info. Is this way still the best way to get the data?

Answer (score 1):

How about using `.annotate`, annotating the other field onto modelA from modelB and then defining it as a charfield(or whatever the type is) on the serializer?

Something like

```
queryset = ModelA.objects.all().annotate(other_field_on_model_b=F('ModelB__other_field_on_model_b'))
```

then in the seralizer

```
class SerializerA(ModelSerializer):
    some_field = CharField()
    some_other_field = CharField()
    other_field_on_model_b = CharField(required=False) #or whatever the field type is.
    class Meta:
        model = ModelA
        fields = ('some_field', 'some_other_field', 'other_field_on_model_b')
```

Could do the annotation in `get_queryset()` or in the end point itself.